# How to get the outuput in the correct format

Tags: python

[image]

```
def read_ndfa(file : open) -> {str:{str:{str}}}:
    pass
```

file =

```
start;0;start;1;start;0;near
near;1;end
end
```

correct output = `{'end': {}, 'start': {'1': {'start'}, '0': {'start', 'near'}}, 'near': {'1': {'end'}}}`

I need to write a function that takes a file as an input to get the correct output as above. however, I have no idea how to create the inner dictionary by using zip function. can someone show me the correct way to do it? Many thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me the relationship between the input and expected output... could you elaborate?

Comment: I have post  a image to explain the relationship

Comment: I managed to figure it out anyway, but *do not post images to explain your problem*. Write out the text in the question

Comment: Also, you should show your own attempts at a solution. This isn't a code-writing service. Honestly, this should be straightforward without zip. I don't think zip really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this :

```
import csv

f = open('data.csv', 'r')

r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

out = {}

for row in r:
    out[row[0]] = {} # Set the top level key

    # Loop on all odd elements
    for pos in range(1, len(row), 2):

        if row[pos] in out[row[0]]:
            # Add the element to the existing set
            out[row[0]][row[pos]].add(row[pos+1])
        else:
            # Create a new set for the key
            out[row[0]][row[pos]] = set([row[pos+1]])

print(out)

f.close()
```

Which gives :

```
{'near': {'1': {'end'}}, 'end': {}, 'start': {'0': {'near', 'start'}, '1': {'start'}}}
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helps

Comment: @Stephan you can accept this answer, if it solves your problem.

Comment: oh, I think I just did